# What is the precise definition of a 'landscape' in the context of differential geometry on manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I'm pursuing some research into molecular dynamics and a common concept that comes up is the notion of a manifold that represents the free energy with respect to the degrees of freedom in a system. However the nomenclature particularly refers to these manifolds as 'landscapes'.

This usually comes up when the author refers to factors that 'change the shape' of the landscapes (i.e temperature). Is there a formal definition of landscape or is it a loose term referring to a general class of manifolds?

Example: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2143098/pdf/7613459.pdf

Comment: maybe he meant to say $\mathbb{R}^n$, as manifolds are locally looks like  $\mathbb{R}^n$, just a guess.

Comment: @ZenoSan Yeah I suppose, that's what I thought but then I don't understand why he wouldn't just define it a standard way. I thought that maybe the existence of a factor that changes the shape of the manifold, while keeping the number of dimensions the same differentiates a landscape from a standard manifold on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is usually taken to be static in nature.

Comment: This is not a very good question for math.stackexchange, because it is not a mathematics question. It is instead a question about the mathematical terminology used by people who do molecular dynamics. Generally speaking it's no surprise that specialized terminology varies widely across different branches of human inquiry, but for a specific answer you should probably consult a molecular dynamicist.

Comment: @LeeMosher I understand your point, however it occurred to me that the reader was assumed to know the *technical* meaning of landscape, as they use both 'manifold' and 'landscape' in the same context but not interchangeably. Given the roots of the originating in differential geometry, it felt appropriate to pose the question here. The answer posted by AbdulHalim appears to point to this definition:
https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Analytic_landschaft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of german word "Landschaft" ,the english "landscape" is also used.
The terms is used and related in analytic 'Landschaft',analytic relief,modulus surface.The geometric image of the modulus |f(z)| of the analytic function f(z),where z=x+iy.The analytic'landschaft' of a function f(z) is the surface over the (x,y) plane with z-co-ordinate |f(z)|.An analytic 'landschaft' sometimes provides a good illustration of the behavior of specific functions.

Comment: much appreciated!

Comment: So a landscape, more generally, appears to be a manifold formed by taking parameters $x,y$ and producing $g(x,y) = z$ and then taking the modulus of the geometric image of z $f( \cdot)$ as the third component of the coordinates